# Xcode4 project with custom configuration name vs dependency library Debug/Release?

Tags: iphone, xcode, project, xcode4

I have an Xcode app project with available configurations "Foo", "Bar", and "Baz".  This project is dependent on a static library with configurations "Debug" and "Release".

Xcode4 is building products from the app project into a "Foo-iphoneos" directory, and products from the library project into a "Release-iphoneos" directory.

What is the best practice for having these two projects share the same build products directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following path to library search paths for any non-standard configuration:

```
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../Release-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
```

This works for me with xcode 4.6. I'm not sure if there is a way to control which configuration will get built for the dependent sibling projects, but for my purposes Release was what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that if your dependent projects have the same configuration names as the main project (i.e. Foo, Bar, Baz), then Xcode will match them up and build using the same configuration.

So, if you wanted a debug build instead of a release build, you could duplicate the Debug configuration and call it Foo. If you do not really need both, you could rename the configuration instead of duplicating it, but with example names like Foo, I am not sure what would make sense for your situation.

However, the title mentions Xcode 4. The technique described above is what I used to do in Xcode 3; I haven't figured out how to manage these configurations yet in Xcode 4. I'm trying to figure that out now.

Update: To manage configurations in Xcode 4, you can click on the name of your project or dependent project towards the top of the project navigator (where all your files/folders are listed on the left side). In the main window, select Info (the other tab is Build Settings). You will then see the Configuration section where you can add/delete/rename your configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if your target and dependencies' configurations don't match then the dependencies will be built with the Release configuration.

I couldn't find a way to customize that.